# how to validate textbox in jquery without using alertbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In this, the textbox must allow strings only.
But without using alert box how to validate a text box in jquery.
Can anyone explain to me? And how to validate a number in jquery.

```
$(function () {
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            Title: "required",
            lan: "required",
            Lati: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            Title: "Please enter your Country name",
            lan: "please enter longitude vale",
            Lati: "Please enter lattitude value",
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" id="register-form">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Title</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="Title" id="Title" class="as_input" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Lan</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="lan" id="Lan" class="as_input" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Lat</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="50" name="Lati" id="Lati" class="as_input" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to be done by check on keyup,blur , sample below code is for numeric and alphabet ,
**[JS FIDDLE SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3njfC/)**

```
 $('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
 });

  $('.numbersOnly').blur(function () {
           this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
   });

   $('.alphabetsOnly').keyup(function () {
           this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\ .]/g, '');
   });

   $('.alphabetsOnly').blur(function () {
         this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\ .]/g, '');
   });
```

You just need to add these class to respected textbox.

Comment: I have one more doubt.Is numbersOnly name for textbox

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Altynbek92/m1x3ko8g/

```
<input id="tt" type="button" value="click me!">
<input type="text" id="text1">

$('#tt').click(function() {   
var tb1 = $("#text1");
    if (isNullOrWhitespace(tb1.val())) {
        tb1.tooltip({ items: tb1, content: "Displaying on click"});
        tb1.tooltip("open");
    } else {
        tb1.tooltip( "option", { disabled: true } );
    }
});

function isNullOrWhitespace(input) {
    if (input == null) return true;
    return input.replace(/\s/g, '').length < 1;
}
```

Comment: This answer is in the Low Quality Posts review queue because it's just code with no explanation. Please improve your answer by explaining what your code does and how it answers the question. Please read [this advice on answering programming questions helpfully](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx).